# Regex for URL without path

Tags: python, regex, url

I know there are many solutions, articles and libraries for this case, but couldn't find one to match my case. I'm trying to write a regex to extract a URL(which represent the website) from a text (a signature of a person in an email), and has multiple cases:

- Could contain http(s):// , or not
- Could contain www. , or not
- Could have multiple TLD such as "test.com.cn"

Here are some examples:

```
www.test.com
https://test.com.cn
http://www.test.com.cn
test.com
test.com.cn
```

I've come up with the following regex:

```
(https?://)?(www\.)?\w{2,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})?$
```

But there are two main problems with this, because the signature can contain an email address:

1. It (wrongly) capture the TLDs of emails like this one:  name.surname@test2.com
2. It doesn't capture URLS in the middle of a line, and if I remove the $ sign at the end, it captures the `name.surname` part of the last example

For (1) I tried using `negative lookbehind`, adding this `(?<!@)` to the beginning, the problem is that now it captures `est2.com` instead of not matching it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use `\b` (boundary) instead of `$` (and at the beginning as well) and exclude `@` in negative lookbehind and lookahead:

```
(?<!@|\.|-)\b(https?://)?(www\.)?\w{2,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})?\b(?!@|\.|-)
```

Edit: exclude the dot (and all non alphanumeric characters likely to occur in an URL/email address) in your lookarounds to avoid matching `name.middlename` in `name.middlename.surname@test2.com` or `com.cn` in `name.surname@test2.com.cn`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547940/13525512) for the list of characters

Comment: Thanks, it almost works but now it catches `com.cn` in `name.surname@test2.com.cn`

Comment: Haha right! my edit should apply to the lookbehind as well! Changing it right away